# Dependencies in SDK version 28

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am working on Android Studio SDK version 28 and when I did gradle sync I got three errors:

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:28.1.0
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.0
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:28.1.0`
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: you should use 28.0.0-rc01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually telling the truth. There is no `28.1.0` available dependency.

Use `28.0.0` (*[Latest **stable** version by now](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0)*) for support libraries dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

They also should be the same version.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Please use `implementation` rather than `compile`